# Cambiar entre dos bases de datos MySQL con botón y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Lo que quiero hacer es *cambiar/alternar entre bases de datos*; iniciar con una base de datos por default **(base1)** y al dar click cambiar a **base2** y volver a dar click y usar la **base1**

Lo que he logrado es que con dos botones y un ajax mandar por un parametro el nombre de la base de datos y con **$_GET** se modifica la conexión.

¿Hay una mejor forma de hacerlo?
mi jefe me comento que se puede hacer con un **COMBO** pero soy nuevo en php y sólo encontré array´s

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
     <ul class="nav">
       <li><a href="">BD</a>
         <ul>
           <li><button value='base1' onclick="accion('base1')">BASE1</button></li>
           <li><button value='base1' onclick="accion('base2')">BASE2</button></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
    <div id="base"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function accion(idbuscar) {

       var text = idbuscar;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url:  'conn.php',
          data: {text: text}, //mandas una variable al archivo php
          dataType: 'text',
                success:function(data){
                    $("#base").html('<br>AJAX call was successful! <br>'+ data);

               },
               error: function(data){
                 alert('Error '+console.log(data));

               }
             });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
```

```php
<?php
if(isset($_GET['text'])){
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","aed5e9a88f",$_GET['text'])
or die ("no se ha podido conectar a la BD");
$sql="SELECT * FROM base1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<br> nombre:  ".$row["nombre"]." |email:  ".$row["email"];
}
}
 ?>
```

Comment: A que te referis con una mejor forma? un combo es un elemento de la vista. en html es un select.

Comment: bueno, hay otra forma?
es que no estoy seguro de hacerlo así

Comment: Tal vez tu pregunta deberia especificar porque no estas seguro de hacerlo asi. O que problemas te genera esta solucion.

Comment: Si tu jefe te dice que con un combo, se refiere a la forma en que seleccionas la base de datos. De momento estas usando un boton dentro de una lista. Prueba usando la etiqueta <select> para la seleccion de la base de datos